# Slider not showing and no error messages in console

Tags: javascript, wordpress

one of my clients is having trouble with a slider, the slide rits self isn't showing and in the chrome dev tools its showing no errors. I'm stuck.

http://www.theresawild.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CSS `.avia-slideshow li{opacity:1;}`